# Read records in a text file randomly and display selected information

Tags: python

I want to select a random record from an existing text file and display the information in a specific format.  For example only see the first letter of each word in one of the fields.

```
import random
graderecord=random.choice(grade.readlines())

field=graderecord.split(",")
name=field[0]
expected_grade=field[1]
actual_grade=field[2]

words=name.split()
initials=""
for word in words:
    initials=initials+word[0]
```

At the minute my program displays the result I want for one record in the file "pupil initials, expected grade, actual grade").  How would I repeat this so that I can display another record when I want to?

Comment: Store the read lines in a var, and run the entire in a while loop..
`while True:` or `while <condition>`

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "when I want to?" Should the program wait for an input by your side to search for another random line?

Answer (score 0):

Just abstract the code in a function that accepts a list of strings:

```
def get_random_record(records):
    graderecord = random.choice(records)
    field = graderecord.split(",")

    name = field[0]
    expected_grade = field[1]
    actual_grade = field[2]

    words = name.split()
    initials = ""
    for word in words:
        initials = initials+word[0]

    return initials

records = grade.readlines()

for i in range(10):
    print(get_random_record(records))
```